# How to pass RGBA color into Seaborn PairGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have defined a PairGrid function, which works fine

```
grid = sns.PairGrid(data= df,
                vars = ['sugarpercent', 'pricepercent', 'winpercent'], size = 3)

# Map the plots to the locations
grid = grid.map_upper(plt.scatter, color = 'darkred')
grid = grid.map_upper(corr)
grid = grid.map_upper(sns.regplot, line_kws={'color': 'darkred'}, lowess=True)
```

However, I want to use `RGBA (12, 50, 196, 0.6)` instead of darkred for both scatter and regplot function. I tried to replace the tuple `'color': (12, 50, 196, 0.6)`, and got this error: `ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range`.
Having read a bit, it seems that I need to iterate over and assign the color to each data point. Is that correct? How do you do that when the plotting function is passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. RGB(A) values need to be between 0–1, while your values `(12, 50, 196)` are (most likely) between 0–255.

change to: `color=(12/255, 50/255, 196/255, 0.6)`

```py
my_color = (12/255, 50/255, 196/255, 0.6)

g = sns.PairGrid(penguins)
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, color=my_color)
g.map_upper(sns.regplot, line_kws={'color': my_color}, lowess=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works for me now. I was switching between Seaborn and Plotly, so it was all over my head. Plus I need some more coffee lol